# Unique constraint for a NodeEntity

Tags: spring, unique, neo4j, unique-constraint, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring Data, Neo4j and Jackson to serve a JSON API. I have a simple User class like this:

```
@NodeEntity
@JsonAutoDetect(JsonMethod.NONE)
public class User {
    @GraphId Long internalId;
    @Indexed String id;

    public User() {}

    public User(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

I'm using `@Indexed` to use the `id` attribute in the URLs. Is there any possibility to set this field as *unique*? (as in a RDBMS)

Now I can create many users with the same id:

```
Neo4jTemplate template;
...
template.save(new User("testid"));
template.save(new User("testid"));
```

I'd like an exception on the second `save` or, at least, I'd like to replace the first user in the DB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ask on Stack Overflow. In the same day [a new Spring-Data-Neo4j milestone is released](http://www.springsource.org/node/3492)... that fixes the [DATAGRAPH-181](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-181) issue and add support for unique indexes.

Just need to annotate the field like this:

```
@Indexed(unique=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to use @GraphId for that?

Comment: It seems that `@Graphid`s are autogenerated (and only `Long`). I'd like to set the IDs myself.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/2.0.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/annotation/GraphId.html says: "type of the field should be long", means is can be also other types? ^^